# Obtaining the last five transactions performed by a particular transactionID from a JSON file

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am writing a python script that is supposed to obtain data from a JSON object and for each instance of a dictionary key called 'transactionID', the program should be able to return the last five transactions performed by a particular transactionID. I'm not certain on how to continue after importing the JSON file, obtaining the dictionary holding the 'transactionID' field from the file and storing it in a list called transaction_details. The JSON object comes in the format below;

```
[{
    "transactionData":{
                    "transactionID":"tyeeeg5667557", 
                    "deviceID": "uasjaslsa", 
                    "IMEI":"ssjdjdssd", 
                    "transactionDate": "12-12-2019", 
                    "time": "11:40", 
                    "accountDetails": {"userID": "kilopol", "creationdate": "21-12-2019"}, 
                    "Amount": {"amount": 2000, "units": "UGX", "qty":1}, 
                    "paymentMethod": {"name": "mobile money"}, 
                    "productdetails": {"productid": "12jfjf", "name": "airtime", "units":"UGX"}
                    },
"locationdetails": {"address":"Ntinda-Kampala", "street": "Chwa 2 Ntinda-Nakawa"},
"api key": "a9dd1d0f-a605-499a-9618-c449065d34bb", 
"callbackUrl": "http://clinet.com/method", 
"clientid": "5ce7baf3ffd59f2633ed64a3", 
"receptiontime": 1559297122942
},
{
    "transactionData":{
                    "transactionID":"yetrw5667557", 
                    "deviceID": "uweyjaslsa", 
                    "IMEI":"ssycvjdssd", 
                    "transactionDate": "12-12-2019", 
                    "time": "11:40", 
                    "accountDetails": {"userID": "kimange", "creationdate": "21-12-2019"}, 
                    "Amount": {"amount": 4000, "units": "UGX", "qty":2}, 
                    "paymentMethod": {"name": "airtel money"}, 
                    "productdetails": {"productid": "12jfjf", "name": "airtime", "units":"UGX"}
                    },
"locationdetails": {"address":"Kamwokya-Kampala", "street": "Chwa 2 Ntinda-Nakawa"},
"api key": "a9dd1d0f-a605-499a-9618-c449065d34bb", 
"callbackUrl": "http://clinet.com/method", 
"clientid": "5ce7bafutwf2633ed64a3", 
"receptiontime": 1559297122942
},
{
    "transactionData":{
                    "transactionID":"tyeeeg5667557", 
                    "deviceID": "uweyjaslsa", 
                    "IMEI":"ssycvjdssd", 
                    "transactionDate": "12-12-2019", 
                    "time": "11:40", 
                    "accountDetails": {"userID": "kimange", "creationdate": "21-12-2019"}, 
                    "Amount": {"amount": 4000, "units": "UGX", "qty":2}, 
                    "paymentMethod": {"name": "airtel money"}, 
                    "productdetails": {"productid": "12jfjf", "name": "airtime", "units":"UGX"}
                    },
"locationdetails": {"address":"Kamwokya-Kampala", "street": "Chwa 2 Ntinda-Nakawa"},
"api key": "a9dd1d0f-a605-499a-9618-c449065d34bb", 
"callbackUrl": "http://clinet.com/method", 
"clientid": "5ce7bafutwf2633ed64a3", 
"receptiontime": 1559297122942
},
{
"transactionData":{
                    "transactionID":"tyeeeg5667557", 
                    "deviceID": "uasjaslsa", 
                    "IMEI":"ssjdjdssd", 
                    "transactionDate": "12-12-2019", 
                    "time": "11:40", 
                    "accountDetails": {"userID": "kilopol", "creationdate": "21-12-2019"}, 
                    "Amount": {"amount": 2000, "units": "UGX", "qty":1}, 
                    "paymentMethod": {"name": "mobile money"}, 
                    "productdetails": {"productid": "12jfjf", "name": "airtime", "units":"UGX"}
                    },
"locationdetails": {"address":"Gulu", "street": "Burton Street"},
"api key": "a9dd1d0f-a605-499a-9618-c449065d34bb", 
"callbackUrl": "http://clinet.com/method", 
"clientid": "5ce7baf3ffd59f2633ed64a3", 
"receptiontime": 1559297122942
},
{
"transactionData":{
                    "transactionID":"tyeeeg5667557", 
                    "deviceID": "uasjaslsa", 
                    "IMEI":"ssjdjdssd", 
                    "transactionDate": "12-12-2019", 
                    "time": "11:40", 
                    "accountDetails": {"userID": "kilopol", "creationdate": "21-12-2019"}, 
                    "Amount": {"amount": 2000, "units": "UGX", "qty":1}, 
                    "paymentMethod": {"name": "mobile money"}, 
                    "productdetails": {"productid": "12jfjf", "name": "airtime", "units":"UGX"}
                    },
"locationdetails": {"address":"Ntinda-Kampala", "street": "Chwa 2 Ntinda-Nakawa"},
"api key": "a9dd1d0f-a605-499a-9618-c449065d34bb", 
"callbackUrl": "http://clinet.com/method", 
"clientid": "5ce7baf3ffd59f2633ed64a3", 
"receptiontime": 1559297122942
},
{
"transactionData":{
                    "transactionID":"ygdras557", 
                    "deviceID": "uasjaslsa", 
                    "IMEI":"ssjdjdssd", 
                    "transactionDate": "12-12-2019", 
                    "time": "11:40", 
                    "accountDetails": {"userID": "kilopol", "creationdate": "21-12-2019"}, 
                    "Amount": {"amount": 2000, "units": "UGX", "qty":1}, 
                    "paymentMethod": {"name": "mobile money"}, 
                    "productdetails": {"productid": "12jfjf", "name": "airtime", "units":"UGX"}
                    },
"locationdetails": {"address":"Ntinda-Kampala", "street": "Chwa 2 Ntinda-Nakawa"},
"api key": "a9dd1d0f-a605-499a-9618-c449065d34bb", 
"callbackUrl": "http://clinet.com/method", 
"clientid": "5ce7baf3ffd59f2633ed64a3", 
"receptiontime": 1559297122942
},
{
    "transactionData":{
                    "transactionID":"tyeeeg5667557", 
                    "deviceID": "uasjaslsa", 
                    "IMEI":"ssjdjdssd", 
                    "transactionDate": "7-7-2019", 
                    "time": "11:40", 
                    "accountDetails": {"userID": "kilopol", "creationdate": "21-12-2019"}, 
                    "Amount": {"amount": 6700, "units": "UGX", "qty":1}, 
                    "paymentMethod": {"name": "mobile money"}, 
                    "productdetails": {"productid": "12jfjf", "name": "airtime", "units":"UGX"}
                    },
"locationdetails": {"address":"Ntinda-Kampala", "street": "Chwa 2 Ntinda-Nakawa"},
"api key": "a9dd3d9f-a605-499a-9618-c449065d34bb", 
"callbackUrl": "http://clinet.com/method", 
"clientid": "5ce7baf3ffd59f2633ed64a3", 
"receptiontime": 1559297122942
}
]
```

I need some help on how to implement this, continuing from the code below, proceeding from the point at which I created a list called transaction_details to hold the dictionary containing the transactionID key.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json


class ExtractData(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def obtainLastFiveTransactions(self):
        client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        database = client['database']
        collection = database['collection']

        with open(self.file) as f_obj:
            data_file = json.load(f_obj)
            collection.insert_many(data_file)
            data_received = collection.find({})

            for dict_data in data_received:
                for key, value in dict_data.items():
                    if key == 'transactionData':
                        transactionDataValues = value
                        transaction_details = []
                        for key, value in transactionDataValues.items():
                            if key == 'transactionID':
                                transaction_details.append(transactionDataValues)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and remove the Pymongo library which has nothing to do with what you're asking. It would also be helpful if you showed sample JSON data that included more than one `"transactionData"` entry.

Comment: I've made the changes you requested for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most efficient solution, but this snippet reads the json in, creates a dictionary holding the transactionIds as keys, and then appends 5 newest transactions sorted by transactionDate to the dictionary.

#### For all transactionIds:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

transaction_dict = {}

with open(json_file) as f_obj:
    data = json.load(f_obj)

    # Sort list of transactions by transactionDate
    data_sorted = sorted(
        data,
        key=lambda k: datetime.strptime(k['transactionData']['transactionDate'], "%d-%m-%Y").timestamp(),
        reverse=True
)

    # Make a dictionary with transactionIds as keys
    for transaction in data_sorted:
        transactionId = transaction['transactionData']['transactionID']
        transaction_dict[transactionId] = []

    # Append the 5 newest transaction for appropriate key
    for transaction in data_sorted:
        transactionId = transaction['transactionData']['transactionID']
        if len(transaction_dict[transactionId]) < 6:
            transaction_dict[transactionId].append(transaction)
```

#### For a particular transaction:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

transaction_key = 'xxxx'
transaction_dict = {
    transaction_key: []
}

transactions = []

with open(json_file) as f_obj:
    data = json.load(f_obj)

    for transaction in data:
        if transaction['transactionData']['transactionID'] == transaction_key:
            transactions.append(transaction)

    # Sort list of transactions by transactionDate
    data_sorted = sorted(
        transactions,
        key=lambda k: datetime.strptime(k['transactionData']['transactionDate'], "%d-%m-%Y").timestamp(),
        reverse=True
    )

    # Append the 5 newest transaction for appropriate key
    for transaction in transactions:
        if len(transaction_dict[transaction_key]) < 6:
            transaction_dict[transaction_key].append(transaction)
```

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: I applied exactly that, and chose to work with the key 'userID' instead of the transactionID, and it worked just fine!

Comment: Glad that it was of help! @GibbsHerbertAkena